# PHP 5.x foreach internal array pointer issue

Tags: php, arrays

Let's see this loop:

```
$tomb = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($tomb as $x) {
    echo $x . '<br/>';
}
var_dump(current($tomb));
```

It displays:

```
1
2
3
bool(false)
```

It's correct, because the internal pointer advanced on every iteration, and on end it points over on array, current() returns false.

But this:

```
$tomb = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($tomb as $x) {
    echo $x . ' : ' . current($tomb) . '<br/>';
}
var_dump(current($tomb));
```

Displays:

```
1 : 2
2 : 2
3 : 2
int(2)
```

Why? The internal pointer not advanced on every iteration, only once. The documentaion under current() says: "It does not move the pointer i
n any way". Why the internal pointer only advanced by one, and not all of iterations? And why the current() affects the internal pointer?

Comment: I don't have the same result : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfd8e174ad9cdb01da7858343e2a8c838e696aa5

Comment: @executable You're running php 7.x he's asking for 5.x

Comment: Similar case was mentioned here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php#116128 (5.2.4 to 5.6.29)

Comment: @PavelTřupek Not exactly the same case, because unset() changed the array, current() not.